# SettingWithCopyWarning when setting datetime value in pandas Series

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am getting a SettingWithCopyWarning when setting a value in a pandas Series using iloc. I am using pandas 0.21.1 and python 3.6.7

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone

tz = timezone('CET')
ambiguous_dst = True

expected_dt_series = pd.Series([
    datetime(2018, 10, 28, 1),
    datetime(2018, 10, 28, 2),
    datetime(2018, 10, 28, 3),
    datetime(2018, 10, 28, 4),
])
expected_dt_series = expected_dt_series.dt.tz_localize(
    tz, ambiguous='NaT')

expected_dt_series.iloc[1] = tz.localize(
    datetime(2018, 10, 28, 2), is_dst=ambiguous_dst) # <- line that causes error

expected_dt_series = expected_dt_series.astype('object')
```

output:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: modifications to a method of a datetimelike object are not supported and are discarded. Change values on the original.
  self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
  x.py:17: SettingWithCopyWarning: modifications to a method of a datetimelike object are not supported and are discarded. Change values on the original.
    datetime(2018, 10, 28, 2), is_dst=ambiguous_dst)
```

1. Why does this happen? I am setting a value in the original series
2. What can I do to avoid this? (Other than turning off the warning)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is really this part that is causing the problem:

`expected_dt_series = expected_dt_series.dt.tz_localize(tz, ambiguous='NaT')`

explicitly tell pandas that this is its own series by using `copy`

```
expected_dt_series = expected_dt_series.dt.tz_localize(
    tz, ambiguous='NaT').copy()

expected_dt_series.iloc[1] = tz.localize(
    datetime(2018, 10, 28, 2), is_dst=ambiguous_dst)
```

Comment: Got it thanks. I got mixed up between the documentation of Series.dt.tz_localize and Series.tz_localize.